# Resize image from photo album

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, writeablebitmapex

I want to get a certain photo from the Camera Roll album, resize it and save it to my isolated storage so I can bind to it later - how would I go about it?

```
    using (var library = new MediaLibrary())
    {
        PictureAlbumCollection allAlbums = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;
        PictureAlbum cameraRoll = allAlbums.Where(album => album.Name == "Camera Roll").FirstOrDefault();
        var CameraRollPictures = cameraRoll.Pictures;
    }
```

Here is how I obtain my photos - my understanding is that I need to somehow write it to a writablebitmap, but I fail to see how to go about it. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Of course you have to use [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Class to re-size an image.

Have a look following code snippet for the same.

```
private void DoResize()
        {
            WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(objBitmapImage);
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
            wBitmap.SaveJpeg(mStream, 50, 50, 0, 100);
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using `WriteableBitmapExWinPhone.dll`

```
private void DoResize()
{
    WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(objBitmapImage);
    wBitmap = wBitmap .Resize(50, 100, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
}
```